# Adding 'HtmlAnchor' from C#

Tags: c#, anchor, htmlcontrols

I want to add a HtmlAnchor to the .ascx control. So far I have the code like this:

```
private void SetPhoneNumber()
    {
        HtmlAnchor htmlAnchor = new HtmlAnchor();
        const string spanTag = @"<span class=""icon phone"">m</span>";
        string anchor = spanTag + Context.CurrentPhoneNumber();
        htmlAnchor.InnerText = anchor;
        Controls.Add(htmlAnchor);
    }
```

This is not solving my purpose as its showing like this:

[image: Instead of span it needs to show a phone icon.]

When it should be rendered in the HTML, it should look like this:

```
 <a href="tel:888.444.4444" class="phone"><span class="icon phone">m </span>888.444.4444</a>
```

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: As a side question - why not do an actual control template with <%=  %> avoiding String.Format and potentially messy hardcoded strings, dealing with obscure html encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`InnerHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innerhtml%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of the anchor tag:

```
HtmlAnchor htmlAnchor = new HtmlAnchor();
const string spanTag = @"<span class=""icon phone"">m</span>";
string anchor = spanTag + Context.CurrentPhoneNumber();
htmlAnchor.InnerHtml = anchor;
Controls.Add(htmlAnchor);
```

Comment: Number is not supposed to go inside the span. Span element is static. When rendered, it should look something like this: <a href="tel:888.882.3837" class="phone"><span class="icon phone">m </span>888.882.3837</a>

Answer (score 1):

change innertext to innerhtml

```
 private void SetPhoneNumber()
{
    HtmlAnchor htmlAnchor = new HtmlAnchor();
    const string spanTag = @"<span class=""icon phone"">m</span>";
    string anchor = spanTag + Context.CurrentPhoneNumber();
    htmlAnchor.InnerHtml = anchor;
    Controls.Add(htmlAnchor);
}
```